# Images are not showing up on .net application

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, image, asp.net-core

Logo shows up on homepage but not on inner images. upon inspecting i get the following path.

Homepage: https://localhost:44377/assets/img/logo.png  (Logo visible)

Inner Page: https://localhost:44377/Employee/assets/img/logo.png  (Logo not visible)

If I change the path to virtual ~/ then logo neither shows up on homepage nor internal pages.

Homepage: https://localhost:44377/~/assets/img/logo.png (Logo not visible)

Inner Page: https://localhost:44377/Employee/~/assets/img/logo.png (Logo not visible)

Comment: The link should be relative or absolute, do you have a logo in all those directories, or just under the site root `assets/img/logo.png`? If it's just under the site root, you need to use a different path...

Comment: It is relative i.e assets/img/logo.png and under site root 
But its url changes on inner pages  where it breaks i.e localhost:44377/Employee/assets/img/logo.png instead of localhost:44377/assets/img/logo.png

Comment: Please show us the code in the page of how you construct the relative paths. On the Employees directory, it should be `../assets/img/logo.png` or something similar. If you just have `/assets/img/logo.png` it will prepend the current path to that, and get what you have.

Comment: Logo is in the Shared/_Layout.cshtml 
https://postimg.cc/8scw4gvL

the employee directory is just inheriting Layout code
https://postimg.cc/Fkkq1YXV

why does the path of logo changes for the inner pages i.e employee

Comment: If all your images are inside assets/img folder, then all your img src value should follow the pattern /assets/img/<filename>.

Comment: the pattern is the same. you can check the code postimg.cc/8scw4gvL

Comment: Using the layout template just provides a template that the page uses. The page is still located, in this case, under `Employees`. You need to use absolute references to the image in the Layout.cs instead of relative ones if you are using it as a template in multiple directories.

Comment: In your layout file, we can find that you are accessing another resources from `assets` folder [inside of web root](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/static-files?view=aspnetcore-3.1#serve-static-files), such as `~/assets/plugins/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css` etc, if `~/assets/img/logo.png` still return 404 status while page loads that image, I'd like to know if loading another static files from assets return 404 too in browser Network tab.

Comment: @FeiHan i have called assests related to bootstrap and javascript with virtual reference instead of relative. they load just fine on all webpages. but when i tried to implement it on images neither relative nor virtual references work. Only exception is the homepage where relative reference for images works.

Comment: @RonBeyer i designed this exact software using the same process with relative urls and it worked just fine. The only difference this time is that i have my images in webroot as "assets/img/logo.png" instead of "images/logo.png". This difference is changing urls of all the images in inner pages  to "localhost: Employees/assets/img/logo.png" (broken image) while previously i wud get "localhost:assets/images/logo.png" (working) on all pages.